# Conversion from TCHAR to char* with unicode char support in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

how to convert TCHAR to char* with unicode characters. i use follwong code

```
//BROWSE FOLDER - Opens a browse folder dialog.
char* browse_folder(void)
{
char *selected_path = NULL;

TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
BROWSEINFO bi = { 0 };

bi.ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_USENEWUI;
LPITEMIDLIST pidl = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);

if (pidl != 0)
{
    // get the name of the folder and put it in path
    SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, path);

    //Set the current directory to path
    SetCurrentDirectory(path);

    // free memory used
    IMalloc* imalloc = 0;
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetMalloc(&imalloc)))
    {
        imalloc->Free(pidl);
        imalloc->Release();
    }
    //selected_path = ;
    USES_CONVERSION;
    selected_path = T2A(path);
}
}
```

i have enabled unicode in visual studio project settings.i am using this function to browse folder i am getting exact values in the path(TCHAR) when i convert it to char* unicode characters are replaced as (?????) symbols.

Comment: If you want char data why don't you use the ansi counterpart of the windows API functions  (ie SHGetPathFromIDListA, SetCurrentDirectoryA ...) ?

Comment: Why do you mix the use of TCHAR and char? Don't think you should try to make any conversion. Just replace char with the corresponding windows data type TCHAR.

Comment: i am using this piece code in npapi and npapi requires char pointer to pass this value to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Since your project supports unicode characters, you should use WideCharToMultiByte() to convert to char*. Try using that.